# Tapo plug using python with PyP100 library login error

Tags: python

I am using the basic script from the repository to try and connect to a Tapo P110 plug. Clearly I am using my ip/email/pword.

```
from PyP100 import PyP110

p110 = PyP110.P110("192.168.X.X", "email@gmail.com", "Password123") #Creating a P110 plug object

p110.handshake() #Creates the cookies required for further methods
p110.login() #Sends credentials to the plug and creates AES Key and IV for further methods

#PyP110 has all PyP100 functions and additionally allows to query energy usage infos
p110.getEnergyUsage() #Returns dict with all the energy usage
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\Add-hoc analysis projects\tapo_plug_energy_monitor\Python\Basic_Tapo_script.py", line 9, in <module>
    p110.getDeviceInfo()
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyP100\PyP100.py", line 236, in getDeviceInfo
    URL = f"http://{self.ipAddress}/app?token={self.token}"     
AttributeError: 'P110' object has no attribute 'token'
```

I should note I tried to ping the ip and all packets transmitted and received correctly. It is login() that causes the error but I have checked login details and they seem to be correct. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was because of an update to the Tapo P110 firmware version 1.0.16

The current solution is to make a small change to PyP100.py see below link.

https://github.com/fishbigger/TapoP100/issues/76